# Prove $[A,B]=i$ for a particular set of operators $A$ and $B$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, commutator

Can anyone show that
$$[A, B] = i$$
where
$$A = \frac{1}{4} (X_1 X_2 + X_2 X_1) \, \quad B ≡ \frac{1}{4} \left(\ln X_2^2 - \ln X_1^2 \right) \, .$$
and $X_1$ and $X_2$ are the quadratures, i.e.
$$X_1 = a + a^+ \quad \text{and} \quad X_2 = i(a^+ - a) \, ?$$

I've been working with $[X_1, X_2]$ but I can't proceed further due the logarithm

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. This is an excellent site for physics questions and answers. We have some rules to keep the quality high. Please see the help center to understand them. This particular post will probably be voted closed because it violates our so-called "homework policy". In short, requests for calculations must show effort and identify the exact point at which you are stuck.

Comment: Oh, also, I edited this post to use [mathjax](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation). Please use it in the future.

Comment: Just plug and chug, given they define the $X$s in terms of $a$s, and operators called $a$ in QM normally follow the commutation relationship $[a_i, a_j] = \delta(i,j)$, you can first find $[X_1, X_2]$, then use that to find $[A,B]$.

Comment: I got stuck because the "ln", I don't know how to proceed

Comment: The standard definition of a function of an operator is the power series expansion. That is, substitute $ln(X)$ for the power series about $X=0$.

Comment: The hardest part of this is presumably the $\ln$ stuff, you may wish to ask the question with a focus on that, if that is what you are concerned about. The basic way that I'd go about this sort of problem is to define $X_1 = x$ and $X_2 = p$ with $[x, p] = [\hat a^\dagger, -i\hat a] + [\hat a, i\hat a^\dagger] = -i(-1) + i(1) = 2i.$ But when $[u, v] = uv-vu = k$ for some constant $k$ then generally $u=k\partial_v$ and $v = -k\partial_u,$ so you know $[x, \ln x^2] = 0$ and then you have $[\partial_x, \ln x] = 1/x.$

Comment: Thanks, I already solved the problem using the relation between an operator and a function of another operator $[x_1,  f(x_2)] = c f'(x_2) where [x_1, x_2] = c$